# Opencv readNetFromTensorflow fails with Unknown enumeration DT_VARIANT

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0

I trained a keras model and saved it as PB as in the below script.

```
import sys
import os
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import callbacks
import time


def freeze_session(session, keep_var_names=None, output_names=None, clear_devices=True):
    """
    Freezes the state of a session into a pruned computation graph.

    Creates a new computation graph where variable nodes are replaced by
    constants taking their current value in the session. The new graph will be
    pruned so subgraphs that are not necessary to compute the requested
    outputs are removed.
    @param session The TensorFlow session to be frozen.
    @param keep_var_names A list of variable names that should not be frozen,
                          or None to freeze all the variables in the graph.
    @param output_names Names of the relevant graph outputs.
    @param clear_devices Remove the device directives from the graph for better portability.
    @return The frozen graph definition.
    """
    graph = session.graph
    with graph.as_default():
        freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
        output_names = output_names or []
        output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()]
        input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
        if clear_devices:
            for node in input_graph_def.node:
                node.device = ''
        frozen_graph = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            session, input_graph_def, output_names, freeze_var_names)
        return frozen_graph
        

start = time.time()
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
DEV = False
argvs = sys.argv
argc = len(argvs)

if argc > 1 and (argvs[1] == "--development" or argvs[1] == "-d"):
  DEV = True


epochs = 2

train_data_path = 'data/train'
validation_data_path = 'data/test'

"""
Parameters
"""
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
batch_size = 32
samples_per_epoch = 24
validation_steps = 24
nb_filters1 = 32
nb_filters2 = 64
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
pool_size = 2
classes_num = 2
lr = 0.0004

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters1, conv1_size, conv1_size, padding ="same", input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters2, conv2_size, conv2_size, padding ="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

"""
Tensorboard log
"""
log_dir = './tf-log/'
tb_cb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0)
cbks = [tb_cb]

model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=cbks)

target_dir = './models/'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
model.save('./mymodels/model')
pred_node_names = [None]
pred = [None]
for i in range(1):
    pred_node_names[i] = "output_node"+str(i)
    pred[i] = tf.identity(model.outputs[i], name=pred_node_names[i])

frozen_graph = freeze_session(tf.keras.backend.get_session(), output_names=[out.op.name for out in model.outputs])
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, './', 'xor.pbtxt', as_text=True)
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, './', 'xor.pb', as_text=False)
#Calculate execution time
end = time.time()
dur = end-start

if dur<60:
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"seconds")
elif dur>60 and dur<3600:
    dur=dur/60
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"minutes")
else:
    dur=dur/(60*60)
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"hours")
```

Post that I want to load the model in opencv to perform the predictions but readNetFromTensorflow() fails with the following error

```
[libprotobuf ERROR D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:292] Error parsing text-format opencv_tensorflow.GraphDef: 700:9: Unknown enumeration value of "DT_VARIANT" for field "type".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Image-Classification-by-Keras-and-Tensorflow-master\Using Tensorflow\classify_opencv.py", line 4, in <module>
    tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('xor.pb','xor.pbtxt')
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp:54: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: xor.pbtxt in function 'cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie
```

I went through the .pbtxt file, it indeed contains DT_VARIANT type which I guess is not defined in 3rd party protobuf.

How do I solve this error?